# Compiled lerna project is not resolving modules of a common library package

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, monorepo, lerna

I have a project that I am using lerna and npm workspaces in.

There is the root folder, where my `lerna.json` etc is.

Then there is the packages folder. Inside the `packages` folder, there are 3 packages: `bdc-client`, `bdc-common`, and `bdc-server`. `bdc-common` contains some common types I'd like to share between the other two packages.

This is how I have things configured currently:

**bdc-common/tsconfig.json**

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "target": "esnext",
        "module": "commonjs",
        "lib": ["esnext", "dom"],
        "esModuleInterop": true,
        "outDir": "dist",
        "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
        "declaration": true,
        "strict": true,
        "skipLibCheck": true,
        "composite": true,
        "rootDir": ".",
        "paths": {
            "@bdc/common/*": ["./*"]
        }
    },
    "exclude": ["node_modules", "dist"],
}
```

**bdc-common/package.json**

```
{
  "name": "@bdc/common",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "scripts": {
    "build": "tsc",
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "pg": "^8.11.0",
    "pg-hstore": "^2.3.4",
    "sequelize": "^6.32.0"
  }
}
```

**bdc-server/tsconfig.json**

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "target": "es6",
        "module": "commonjs",
        "outDir": "dist",
        "strict": true,
        "baseUrl": ".",
        "esModuleInterop": true,
        "skipLibCheck": true,
        "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
        "useUnknownInCatchVariables": false,
        "paths": {
            "@bdc/common/*": ["../bdc-common/*"]
        }
    },
    "references": [
        {
            "path": "../bdc-common"
        }
    ],
    "include": ["src/**/*.ts"]
}
```

Now this seems to all work fine when writing the TypeScript code, the paths resolve and I can compile without problems.

I am importing from "bdc-common" like so:

`import sequelize from "@bdc/common/database/sequelize"`

However, when I run `npm start` within `bdc-server`, I end up getting this error:

> Error: Cannot find module '@bdc/common/database/sequelize'

This is coming from the compiled JavaScript when running.

I've tried everything I can think of, and I've asked ChatGPT only to be told that my tsconfig probably isn't configured properly.

Here is an example of what my `bdc-server/dist` folder looks like after compilation:

[image]

How can I properly configure this project so that I can use these common imports even after compiling?

Comment: Add the common package as dependencies in the other packages package.json files. You also have not defined `main` or `exports` in the common package.json file.

Comment: "exports": {
        "./*": "./dist/*.js"
    } has fixed my issue. I had no idea I could do this. I don't even need those tsconfig properties anymore.